# Issue in facebook login in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am having both web and api login in my project. But when I check now, I found my facebook login is not working in web. I am getting the following error

```
Could not find a valid mapping for path "/omniauth/facebook/callback"
```

I have the following path

```
user_omniauth_callback   GET|POST /omniauth/:action/callback(.:format)   users/omniauth_callbacks#:action
```

and also have method **facebook** in **controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**
I have also included the gems devise, **omniauth** and **omniauth-facebook**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for the question. Updating gems to their newest versions (omniauth 1.6.1 and omniauth-facebook 4.0.0) with:

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0.0'
```

solved the issue.